# Run recursive function one after another in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recursion

I'm trying to run recursive function one after another(run function only after response of first comes)

Here's my code:

```
$scope.downloadImage = function (array) {                        
        var fileUrl = "rest/file/download?filekey=" + array[0].fileKey + "&ask=" + ASK + "&osk=" + OSK;                        
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = fileUrl;
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click(function(){
            array.splice(0, 1);
            if (array.length > 0) {
            $scope.downloadImage(array)
        }
        });
        a.remove();                        
    }
```

But its not running function is called only once.

Comment: you'r function call to downloadImage is inside the click handle. It will be called once you click on the a you just created. Think again about your design, i doubt that you need recursion here.

Comment: yeah i know but if i call downloadImage function after a.click() then my href gets overridden.Please suggest any solution